# Python Regex Match Special Characters

Tags: python, regex

I need a function that can test whether a string has any special characters in it. I'm currently using the following function with no luck:

```
import re

def no_special_characters(s, pat=re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')):
  if pat.match(s):
    print(s + " has special characters")
  else:
    print(s + " has NO special characters")
```

I get the following results:

```
no_special_characters('$@')  # $@ has special characters
no_special_characters('a$@') # a$@ has NO special characters
no_special_characters('$@a') # $@a has special characters
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. How can I test for ANY special characters in a string?

Comment: `re.match` matches the string *from the start*. `re.search` matches in any position. `re.fullmatch` matches the whole string

Comment: You can add `.*` to the start and end of your regex but whether that is the right approach is up for debate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using `match()` here is that it is anchored to the beginning of the string.  You want to find a single special character *anywhere* in the string, so use `search()` instead:

```
def no_special_characters(s, pat=re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')):
    if pat.search(s):
        print(s + " has special characters")
    else:
        print(s + " has NO special characters")
```

You could also keep using `match()` with the following regex pattern:

```
.*[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:].*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `search` function instead of `match` function.

Comment: Hey, just a heads up, the python 3.x tag is for questions about behaviour specific to python 3